# Is it possible to type or cast string[] values as keyof WindowEventMap?

Tags: typescript

Is it possible to type or cast EventTypes to work with the following scenario?

Is it possible to do if EventTypes was a subset of `keyof WindowEventMap`?

```
const EventTypes = [
    "abort",
    ...
    "mouseenter",
    "mouseleave",
    ....
];  //A list of all keyof WindowEventMap strings

function consumeEvent<K extends keyof WindowEventMap>( eventType: keyof WindowEventMap, ev: WindowEventMap[K] ) {
    ....
}

EventTypes.forEach( et => window.addEventListener( et, e => consumeEvent( et, e)));
//`et` causes an error as a parameter to consumeEvent
//Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'keyof WindoEventMap'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your example above, you do just as you suggested and cast the type of the array as a list of keys of `WindowEventMap` rather than arbitrary `string[]` (nitpick, `camelCase` your array, because the capitalization makes it look like a type.)

```
const events = [
  'abort',
  'mouseenter',
  'mouseleave',
] as (keyof WindowEventMap)[];

function consumeEvent<K extends keyof WindowEventMap>(
  eventType: K,
  ev: WindowEventMap[K],
) {}

events.forEach((et) => window.addEventListener(et, (e) => consumeEvent(et, e)));
```

If you want to limit the function to only allow a subset of event types, you can declare the subset with `Extract`:

```
type AllowedEvent = Extract<
  keyof WindowEventMap,
  'abort' | 'mouseenter' | 'mouseleave'
>;

function consumeEvent<K extends AllowedEvent>(
  eventType: K,
  ev: WindowEventMap[K],
) {}

const events = [
  'abort',
  'mouseenter',
  'mouseleave',
] as AllowedEvent[];

events.forEach((et) => window.addEventListener(et, (e) => consumeEvent(et, e)));
```